# How to implement a PHP code to a html button?

Tags: php, html

```
$no = $_POST['no'];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $exec = curl_exec ($ch);
```

See i want to implement the above code to this html code `<p><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p></form>` When a user would press submit then the program should start..

i tried using this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&isset($_POST['no'])) ($ch);`
but it ain't working it just repeats without the $no.
Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can we see some evidence of effort first? What have you tried?

Comment: See i want to implement  the 2nd code to <p><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Bomb!!" /></p></form>
When a user would press submit then the program should start..

Comment: When i added  "if(isset($_POST['submit']))" in the code it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added comments to the code that you posted to make it more clear. Though a lot of this is easily found in google searches.

```
 //Call a function called error_reporting with a parameter with the value of 0.
error_reporting(0); 

//If the user does not have a cookie with the name 'count'
if (!isset($_COOKIE['count'])) {
    //set the cookie 'count' to equal 1
    $cookie = 1;
    setcookie("count", $cookie);
//If the user does have the cookie
} else {
    //increase the number value of the cookie by one
    $cookie = ++$_COOKIE['count'];
    setcookie("count", $cookie);
    //assign the number to the $count variable
    $count = $_COOKIE['count'];
}
```

and

```
//Get the value of the post variable, and assign it to $no
$no = $_POST['no'];
//Create a new session (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)
$ch = curl_init();
//Set some options for the session (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//execute the session (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)
$exec = curl_exec ($ch);
```

and

```
//immediately redirect a user to http://example.com/index.php
//the url has a get parameter with the value of the $no variable
header ("Refresh: 0;url=http://example.com/index.php?m=$no");
```